# Android Studio tells me i need Java jdk 1.8 to use Build tools Build Tools 22.0.0

Tags: java, android

Android Studio tells me i need Java jdk 1.8 to use Build tools Build Tools 22.0.0 but I have jdk-8u101-windows-x64.exe installed is it not enough?

Comment: Installation might not be enough if you have more than one JRE on your machine, you need to make sure Java 8 is your primary JRE by setting up JAVA_HOME (or) edit Android Studio ini files to set Java 8  as JRE for Android studio.

Comment: your jdk may be set in Android studio to use an older version at run/build time. check you project preferences